# JSON object with nested objects, all needing to be casted to classes in Typescript/Angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript

Have done quite a bit of research on this but my situation seems to be a tad more complex than other examples i've seen on stack. I hope my explanation is clear enough to follow!

The API response I am working with is structured as an array of `Customers`. Each `Customer` has methods of its own as well as multiple nested objects. For the purposes of this question I'll focus on the `Addons` nested object (so `Customer.Addons`). `Addons` has some methods as well as an array of objects (addons). Each array item is an `Addon` object. So...I need to cast each level as the prototype of the associated Class.

This seems to work fine for `Customer`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(customer, Customer.prototype)
```

I am stuck on `Addons` even though I am using the same approach:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(customer.addOns, Addons.prototype)
```

And for the array of addons (type `Addon`) I am iterating through like so. THIS seems to be working fine as well:

```
_.each(customer.addOns, (addon: Addon) => {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(addon, Addon.prototype)
})
```

When I console.log this stuff, I can see that the `Customer` object is getting recognized as `Customer`. I can see that array items are correctly getting recognized as type `Addon`, but the `Addons` object, that middle layer, seems to be a plain object.

This image captures what I mean. Parent object of type `Customer`, child named addons with an array of items all of type `Addon`:
[image]

Here is my `Addons` class. It extends a generic class whose sole job is to have an array with some basic CRUD methods. The `getSubtotal` method is just returning a hard coded number for now (for testing) but will ultimately iterate through the associated array in its `super` and add numbers.

```
export class Addons extends PluralOfType<Addon> {

    constructor() {}

    ...

    getSubTotal(): number {
        // eventually will return _.reduce(super.arr, ...) etc
        return 10
    }

}
```

Here is a segment from the `PluralOfType` generic:

```
class PluralOfType<T> {

    public arr: T[] = [];

    getAll(): T[] { return this.arr };

    ...

}
```

In my other typescript files, if I do this:

```
console.log(customer.addOns)
```

I will get the array of addons, each of type `Addon`. If I do this:

```
console.log(customer.addOns.getSubtotal())
```

I will get `10`, which is correct. If I do this, which is a method on addOns superclass:

```
console.log(customer.addOns.getAll())
```

I get undefined. Moreover, because `arr` is public in the superclass, unsure why I can't just call `customer.addOns.arr`.

Clearly I am missing something here. Hopefully it's a simple fix! Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given some class object, `class A {m(){}}`, setting the prototype of an object, say `o`, to `A.prototype` does not construct `A` and then merge the resulting value's members into `o`. It just changes `o`'s prototype. In other words it sets up delegation of member lookup such that, if `o` does not have a requested member, say `m`, then `A.prototype` will be considered and `A.prototype.m` will be reolved.

So, for

```
class PluralOfType {
  arr = [];
  getAll() {return this.arr;}
}
```

and

```
class AddOns extends PluralOfType {
  getSubTotal() {return 10;}
}
```

if we write

```
const o = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(o, AddOns.prototype);
console.log(o.getAll());
```

will print `undefined` because `this` is `o` in the expression `this.arr`.

We would then  likely be tempted to write

```
const addOnsArray = customer.addOns.slice();
Object.setPrototypeOf(customer.addOns, AddOns.prototype);
Object.assign(customer.addOns, new AddOns());
```

But that will make `arr` an empty array which isn't what we actually want.

An unsound and dirty fix for the specific problem is to write

```
const addOnsArray = customer.addOns.slice();
Object.setPrototypeOf(customer.addOns, AddOns.prototype);
customer.addOns.arr = addOnsArray;
```

This in not general enough to be useful.

The entire approach dramatically increases the odds of introducing very serious and difficult to find bugs. It makes the system confusing.

I'm not just talking about arrays, I mean all of it.

You should scrap your entire approach. Don't change the prototypes of any values returned by `JSON.parse` at all.

You probably do not realize how hard you are making your task nor how much the people who inherit your project will hate you.

My recommendation is that you not use classes to define the functionality. If you really want to have methods in your objects add them to the objects directly. However, it would be simpler to keep the functionality outside the objects either as free standing functions or as methods in services. These would receive the object as an argument. Sometimes it does make sense to have functions and data together but this does not work well with serialization.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed explanation. So what would be the recommended approach for "assigning" or "associating" the list of customers returned from the API with a class such that there are some available methods on each customer that can be accessed throughout the application? Or are you saying this is just not recommended?

Comment: My recommendation is that you not use classes to define the functionality. If you really want to have methods on your objects add them to the objects but it would be simpler to keep the functionality outside the objects either as free standing functions or as methods in services. These would receive the object as an argument. Sometimes it does make sense to have functions and data together but this does not work well  with serialization.